# How to translate "social media manager" to Esperanto?

Tags: translation

I'm thinking social is *socia*, media could be *komunikila* and manager could be *administranto*, but that all feels very clunky. Any idea for something that sounds much better?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that the best translation for *social media* is *sociaj retoj*. The job of a social media manager is not to administer social media, but to represent another organization in social media by communicating the organization's goals and ongoing work to the general public via social media. For this reason, I wouldn't say *soci-reta administranto/administristo*, but rather *soci-reta komunikisto*.